# AAR class library stored in bintray doesn't link to the extended class

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, aar, bintray

I created an Android library made by a class named WordUtils2 which extends the Java class WordUtils.
The entire project can be found in github here:
https://github.com/dequadelisonz/WordUtils2

I also published the generated aar file into BinTray so to be able to use it through Gradle in other Android projects.
The project builds fine and there seems to be no problems.

But when I include it in other Android projects by adding this row in the gradle.build file of the module:
compile(group: 'it.code.martin', name: 'wordutils2', version: '1.0.0', ext: 'aar')
I get the following error in gradle messages:

> Error:(56, 36) error: cannot access WordUtils class file for
>   org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils not found

It looks like the original Wordutils class from where I extended my class cannot be reached.

Here below I report the Activity code:

```
package code.martin.it.wordutilstest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import it.code.martin.WordUtils2;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText mEditText;
    private TextView mTextview;
    private Button mOkBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mTextview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mOkBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        mOkBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String response= WordUtils2.wordToNumberIt(mEditText.getText().toString());
        mTextview.setText(response);
    }
}
```

and the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "code.martin.it.wordutilstest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile(group: 'it.code.martin', name: 'wordutils2', version: '1.0.0', ext: 'aar')
}
```

Of course I can send further details of my code if needed.

What I'm doing wrong? Android studio is updated to the latest version.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like transitive dependencies aren't working.  Try replacing the dependencies in your build.gradle with this

```
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile(group: 'it.code.martin', name: 'wordutils2', version: '1.0.0', ext: 'aar’){
    transitive=true}
}
```

If that doesn't work, I'd recommend downloading the correct apache commons Jar and building the library with that instead of using gradle dependencies.

Comment: OK I'll try this WE and let you know. Thanks for suggestion.